# How to read this tiny time number, and whats the improvement between these 2 times

Tags: time

I developed something in c sharp, one option without caching and 2nd option with caching.

Without caching the time returned by the app is: : 00:00:00.3873553
How do I read that? its that 387 milliseconds?

With caching: 00:00:00.0000176

Is this nanoseconds, microseconds? how can I read this?

Now, If I want to compare both, whats the % improvement?

Comment: Yes, it is milliseconds. The time format is pretty standard.

Comment: From that sample, it is 0. The format is: `HH:mm:ss.fffffff...` `f` is the fractional part.

Comment: if you read it in milliseconds yet, but it took 176 something, what is that something? how do I read that number?  If I want to compare both numbers to see the improvement how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fractionall part represents milliseconds. Four heading zeros in `0000176` are indicating
a value of 0.0176 ms.

387 ms is 21988 times 0.0176 ms. With caching you need 0.0045% of the time.